# Android set triangle drawable to Button drawable left

Tags: android, button, geometry

i need some explanation how to set triangle.xml to Button drawable left.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="13%"
            android:pivotY="-40%"
            android:toDegrees="45" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="#F000" />

                <solid android:color="@color/Lime" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

So i have drawable of triangle and it wont show up when i put it as DrawableLeft of button.

is there are other way to make triangle as pure shape or some method to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad found my problem. It needs to set size.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="13%"
            android:pivotY="-40%"
            android:toDegrees="45" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                ****<size android:width="15dp" android:height="15dp"/>****
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="#F000" />

                <solid android:color="@color/Lime" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Button XML should look like below

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/YourButton"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:text="Name of the button"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawablefilename"
android:onClick="listener"
>
</Button>
```

In your Activity.java file, include this line

```
btnName.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.drawablefilename, 0, 0, 0);
```

It might wor

Comment: well it doesn't. if i make simple rectangle shape, it would work.